# I cannot import pandas in python3 on my mac

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I used pip to install pandas.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rIyN9Rg9szkdlQBj30t9Jnz9LmNuJw-j/view?usp=sharing

I am able to import it in python2. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VmaSGI6SRxXd6Vi1wJP_V0lpGbahkNim/view?usp=sharing

but cannot import this library in python3.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ju5EtgwRYN7Y4Nzgj-V1j3eM-LpoMbHr/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Because you have installed pandas for python2 and not python3. `pip3 install pandas` will install pandas for python3.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install pandas for `python3` as well, and this is because you have both `python2` and `python3` on your machine.

You can use either conda or pip to install pandas, I am familiar with pip, so by using pip run the command:

`pip3 install pandas`

then run `python3`

from `python3` shell you should be able to import pandas as import pandas